# How to remove certain rows from data frame based on other columns in R?

Tags: r

I want to remove certain rows from a data frame based on other entries in other columns in the data frame. For example, If I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
 asd <- data.frame(
  var_1 = as.factor(c("a1", "a2", "a3", "a1", "a2", "a3", "a1", "a2", "a3")),
  var_2 = as.factor(c("a1", "a1", "a1", "a2", "a2", "a2", "a3", "a3", "a3")),
  var_3 = c("NO", "YES","YES","YES","NO", "YES","YES","YES","NO"),
  var_4 = c(0, 2, 4, 2, 0, 7, 4, 7, 0)
)
> asd
  var_1 var_2 var_3 var_4
1    a1    a1    NO     0
2    a2    a1   YES     2
3    a3    a1   YES     4
4    a1    a2   YES     2
5    a2    a2    NO     0
6    a3    a2   YES     7
7    a1    a3   YES     4
8    a2    a3   YES     7
9    a3    a3    NO     0
```

I want to remove every row that has a `NO` in `var_3` column (luckily, the NO's are always equally spaced, so I can use that fact to help remove them)

... and I also want to remove any duplicates. What I mean by duplicates is, for example, row 2 has `a2` & `a1` and row 4 has `a1` and `a2`... these rows are duplicates of each other.

To achieve this I was using the following code:

```
# This line removes all the rows with NO 
asdf <- asd[-seq(1, NROW(asd), by = 4), ]
# This line removes the duplicate rows
asdf <- asdf[!duplicated(t(apply(asdf, 1, sort))), ]
```

This results in:

```
> asdf
  var_1 var_2 var_3 var_4
2    a2    a1   YES     2
3    a3    a1   YES     4
6    a3    a2   YES     7
```

This is the exact result I would like... but I was wondering if there is an easier, less messy way of achieving this result (preferably using base R... but this isn't an unbreakable rule)?

Any suggestion are greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A base R way which avoids the use of `apply` :

`pmin`/`pmax` performs rowwise sorting, with `duplicated` we drop the duplicates and remove rows which have `var3 = 'NO'`.

```
result <- transform(asd, var_1 = pmin(var_1, var_2), var_2 = pmax(var_1, var_2))
subset(result, (!duplicated(result[1:2])) &  var_3 != 'NO')

#  var_1 var_2 var_3 var_4
#2    a1    a2   YES     2
#3    a1    a3   YES     4
#6    a2    a3   YES     7
```

Comment: This is an excellent answer. However, I made a mistake and have forgotten to add a detail to my original question. In my data set, `var_1` and `var_2` are factors... I will edit the question to reflect this fact.

Comment: In that case you need to change the columns to characters for this answer to work.